# How to do Large File Upload with MSGraphClientV3 in SPFx web part

Tags: microsoft-graph-sdks, spfx

I work in a SPFx web part So the client I instantiate is of type MSGraphClientV3

When I use the example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/large-file-upload?tabs=typescript&source=docs

The line

const uploadSession = await LargeFileUploadTask.createUploadSession(_client,fileUpload ,options);

Shows error "Type 'MSGraphClientV3' is missing the following properties from type 'Client': config, httpClient"

So How can I resolve it? or is there another version of LargeFileUploadTask for MSGraphClientV3?

Copilot suggested:

```
async function uploadLargeFile(client: MSGraphClientV3, file: File) {
  // Create an upload session
  const uploadSession = await client.api(`/me/drive/root:/${file.name}:/createUploadSession`).post({
    item: {
      "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename", // if the file already exists, rename the new one
      name: file.name
    }
  });

  const maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024; // Choose a slice size, e.g. 320KB
  const numberOfSlices = Math.ceil(file.size / maxSliceSize);
  let start = 0, end = maxSliceSize;

  for (let sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber < numberOfSlices; sliceNumber++) {
    // Get a slice of the file
    const slice = file.slice(start, end);

    // Upload the slice
    await client.api(uploadSession.uploadUrl).put({
      body: slice,
      headers: {
        'Content-Length': `${slice.size}`,
        'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${file.size}`
      }
    });

    // Update start and end for next slice
    start = end;
    end = start + maxSliceSize;
  }

  // Complete the upload session
  await client.api(uploadSession.uploadUrl).delete();
}
```

but the PUT statement keeps coming up with error:

```
Error: The Content-Range header is missing or malformed.
    at B.constructErrorFromResponse (:2:61288)
    at B.<anonymous> (:2:61567)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at :2:3772
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at l (:2:3520)
    at B.getError (:2:61511)
    at z.<anonymous> (:2:65394)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at s (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_44e0c08e82fafb0cec1e4276427f3ad1.js:2:3627) {statusCode: 400, code: 'invalidRequest', requestId: null, date: Fri Nov 17 2023 18:16:46 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time), body: '{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"The Content-Range header is missing or malformed."}', …}

 help
```